# Why does the transition probability resemble the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern for single slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics, two-level-system

For a two-level system having an arbitrary state, $\Psi=c_1(t)|1\rangle+c_2(t)|1\rangle$ the transition probability from state $|1\rangle$ to state $|2\rangle$ ,i.e., $|c_2(t)|^2$ can be calculated from the rate equations:

$i\dot{c_2}=(\Omega/2)e^{-i(\omega-\omega_{21})t}c_1$
$i\dot{c_1}=(\Omega/2)e^{+i(\omega-\omega_{21})t}c_2$
where $\omega$ is the frequency of the external field, $\omega_{21}=\omega_2-\omega_1$ is the frequency corresponding to the energy difference between the levels $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$, and $\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency which is the hopping rate between $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$. The above equations follow from applying the Rotating Wave Approximation to the original rate equations obtained from the time dependent Schrodinger equation for $\Psi$.

The expression for $|c_2(t)|^2$ comes out to be :
$|c_2(t)|^2=\frac{\Omega}{\Omega^2+(\omega-\omega_{21})^2}\sin^2{\frac{\sqrt{\Omega^2+(\omega-\omega_{21})^2}t}{2}}= \frac{{\Omega}t^2}{4}({\frac{\sin{\chi}}{\chi})}^2$  where $\chi=\frac{\sqrt{\Omega^2+(\omega-\omega_{21})^2}t}{2}$.

So the form of $|c_2(t)|^2$ is like a sinc function (which when plotted against $\sqrt{\Omega^2+(\omega-\omega_{21})^2}$  looks like the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern for a single slit. What is the reason behind this resemblance or what is its significance?

Comment: $c_2$ is a function in time, the diffraction pattern is a function in space. I would not say that this "looks like" one another, the trigonometric functions and their variants appear in all sorts of contexts without some sort of "deep connection" - everything that oscillates in time will have $\sin$ and $\cos$ occurring somewhere, do you think this has some sort of "significance" in other contexts?

Comment: I think there might be some physical explanation behind this resemblance.